# ngram modeling, how to conduct cross-validation

Tags: n-gram, cross-validation

I'm trying to understand how cross validation works in the context of ngram models. I understand that the model essentially lists the probability of each ngram from a corpus in training. However, how does cross validation work? What is the parameter that I should be adjusting ? I know that I want to get 100% accuracy on the validation set, but I'm not sure what I need to adjust to get this to work. Is it something to do with smoothing?

Comment: to whoever that voted to close: please provide comments on why you think this question does not fit.

Comment: I know it's been a while but if you're still interested you might consider asking this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/.